# remove all .svn files and folder using php

Tags: php, svn

by mistaken I upload my code on server with svn files and folders. I don't have access for SSH so can't run commands.
so is there any php code by using which I can delete all .svn folders from my projects.

Comment: You want to delete all folders and files that's ends with .svn?

Comment: http://d.pr/i/I10m
http://d.pr/i/OLmr

please check the droplr images
this project is on old svn which create .svn folders in each folder, so I want to delete all the .svn folder and all the files within it.

Comment: Is it only one folder? or many?

Comment: I am using joomla , so It create .svn folders in every folders of joomla

Comment: 1. Get a list of all the directories ( except .svn ) ones;
 2. Loop through all of them and delete the *.svn* subdirectory; Where is the problem?

Comment: there are so many directories that mean there are so many .svn folder how can I prepare a list

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to just perform a clean export on your workstation, delete what's on the server, and re-upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a solution here it is

copied from [lateralcode](http://%20www.lateralcode.com/remove-svn-php) with little modification

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/work/remove-svn-php/'; // path of your directory 
header( 'Content-type: text/plain' ); // plain text for easy display

// preconditon: $dir ends with a forward slash (/) and is a valid directory
// postcondition: $dir and all it's sub-directories are recursively
// searched through for .svn directories. If a .svn directory is found,
// it is deleted to remove any security holes. 
function removeSVN( $dir ) {
    //echo "Searching: $dir\n\t";

    $flag = false; // haven't found .svn directory
    $svn = $dir . '.svn';

    if( is_dir( $svn ) ) {
        if( !chmod( $svn, 0777 ) )
            echo "File permissions could not be changed (this may or may not be a problem--check the statement below).\n\t"; // if the permissions were already 777, this is not a problem

        delTree( $svn ); // remove the .svn directory with a helper function

        if( is_dir( $svn ) ) // deleting failed
            echo "Failed to delete $svn due to file permissions.";
        else
            echo "Successfully deleted $svn from the file system.";

        $flag = true; // found directory
    }

    if( !$flag ) // no .svn directory
        echo 'No .svn directory found.';
    echo "\n\n";

    $handle = opendir( $dir );
    while( false !== ( $file = readdir( $handle ) ) ) {
        if( $file == '.' || $file == '..' ) // don't get lost by recursively going through the current or top directory
            continue;

        if( is_dir( $dir . $file ) )
            removeSVN( $dir . $file . '/' ); // apply the SVN removal for sub directories
    }
}

// precondition: $dir is a valid directory
// postcondition: $dir and all it's contents are removed
// simple function found at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php#93836
function delTree( $dir ) {
    $files = glob( $dir . '*', GLOB_MARK ); // find all files in the directory

    foreach( $files as $file ) {
        if( substr( $file, -1 ) == '/')
            delTree( $file ); // recursively apply this to sub directories
        else
            unlink( $file );
    }

    if ( is_dir( $dir ) ){
                //echo $dir;
               // die;
        rmdir( $dir ); // remove the directory itself (rmdir only removes a directory once it is empty)

            }
      }

// remove all .svn directories in the 
// current directory and sub directories 
// (recursively applied)
removeSVN($path);
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Finding all the `.svn` folders is a complicated process to do that you need a to use recursive functions.

Link to code: http://pastebin.com/i5QMGm1C

Or view it here:

```
function rrmdir($dir)
{
    foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $path) {
        if(is_dir($path)){
            rrmdir($path);
        }
        else{
            unlink($path);
        }
    }

    foreach(glob($dir . '/.*') as $path) {
        if(is_dir($path)){
            $base_name = basename($path);
            if ($base_name != '..' && $base_name != '.'){
                rrmdir($path);
            }
        }
        else{
            unlink($path);
        }
    }
    rmdir($dir);
}

function delete_dir($base, $dir)
{
    static $count = 0;
    foreach (glob($base . '/*') as $path){
        if(is_dir($path)){
            delete_dir($path, $dir);
        }
    }

    foreach (glob($base . '/.*') as $path){
        if(is_dir($path)){
            $base_name = basename($path);
            if ($base_name != '..' && $base_name != '.'){
                if ($base_name == $dir){
                    rrmdir($path);
                    echo 'Directory (' . $path . ') Removed!<br />';
                    $count++;
                }
                else {
                    delete_dir($path, $dir);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $count;
}

$base = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$dir = '.svn';
$count = delete_dir($base, $dir);

echo 'Total: ' . $count . ' Folders Removed!';
```

Comment: not working
Warning: Missing argument 2 for delete_dir(), called in D:\xampp\htdocs\project\trunk\solution\checkdir.php on line 90 and defined in D:\xampp\htdocs\project\trunk\solution\checkdir.php on line 83

Comment: which type of path I have to provide relative or absolute

Comment: I found a code sample on http://www.lateralcode.com/remove-svn-php/
it is listing all the files but not able to delete files coz of permission error

Comment: You can provide relative or absolute but make sure to not add the last slash for exemple `/a/b/c` not `/a/b/c/`

Comment: I am using $base = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project/trunk/solution/';

but not working..
BTW I got a solution..
thanks for your support.. :)

Comment: @urfusion remove the last slash as i said $base = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project/trunk/solution';

Comment: http://d.pr/i/KENG
http://d.pr/i/Ki8O

not working. here is the code and the screenshot of browser response

Comment: @urfusion I added changing the permissions http://pastebin.com/P74rvC3X don't change anything just download the file and load it!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44618/discussion-between-urfusion-and-rullof)